# GADInterstitial crash in init

Tags: ios, admob

I'm adding Google Admob Fullscreen ads

```
m_interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:ADMOB_FS_ID]; // crash here!!!
m_interstitial.delegate = self;

GADRequest* request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = @[ @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxx" ];
[m_interstitial loadRequest:request];
```

But the app is crash at the init line.
I'm using the Admob ios sdk 7.3.1.
The crash report is below

```
2015-06-03 00:22:17.077 XXX[17213:4624660] -[GADInterstitialViewController setSlot:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e4b6f0
2015-06-03 00:22:17.079 XXX[17213:4624660] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GADInterstitialViewController setSlot:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14e4b6f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x29e9a5a7 0x37a80c77 0x29e9fa6d 0x29e9d949 0x29dceb68 0x1dc9f4 0x19b8b4 0xd3923 0xe488d 0x2d3b437b 0x2d418553 0x2d4184dd 0x2d3945e7 0x29e61275 0x29e5e959 0x29e5ed5b 0x29dabb51 0x29dab963 0x312ea1a9 0x2d3fdc91 0x102011 0x38029aaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Whats the matter?

EDIT: My whole code is below

in AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)showNag
{
    // GAD full
    //    m_interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:ADMOB_FS_ID];
    m_interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    m_interstitial.adUnitID = ADMOB_FS_ID;
    m_interstitial.delegate = self;

    GADRequest* request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = @[ @"251a8278d43c4c1468ce2d807a0ccc72" ];
    [m_interstitial loadRequest:request];
}
```

viewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    AppDelegate* delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [delegate showNag];
}
```

Comment: How are you defining `ADMOB_FS_ID`?

Comment: #define ADMOB_FS_ID             @"ca-app-pub-3913797997090718/7312543782" // real

Comment: That's correct. Can you add all of your AdMob code please.

Comment: I replaced with old version of sdk, but got the same crash. whats wrong? Why can't I find anything on google support?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I had the named GADViewController.h/m files. They made conflict with the GAD framework. The framework also has the same named files. I renamed my files and it works now.